# What is the difference between "one" and "a"?

Tags: articles

Should I say:

> **One** feature of my work is ...

Or

> **A** feature of my work is...

What is the difference?

Comment: "One" draws more attention to this specific feature, while also suggesting that you might (or giving you the option to) discuss other features later. In other words, *one* makes the feature "more special".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are very close semantically. Phonetically, they are a little different. We cannot put phonetic stress on the article *a*. But we can put phonetic stress on the word *one*. When we say "one feature of my work," there is therefore an emphasis on the *one*.

Most commonly, and is as exemplified by your sentence, this emphasis "emphasizes the indefiniteness of the article," i.e. it emphasizes that this is just one of many. Perhaps you don't want the reader to think that this is the *only* feature of your work. The "one" emphasizes that there could be more.

Answer (score 4):

Both a/an and one mean one. The difference is that "one" puts more emphasis on the number such as I have 4 computers and a printer/I have 4 computers and only one printer.

So when you say a feature of my work or one feature of my work, it means the same, with the only difference that "one" is emphatic compared to "a". Grammatically, you can use either of the two.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to disagree a bit here. Though both of the sentences you provided are grammatically sound, such sentence formations are hard to come across, in conversation. Instead the following sentence is spoken:

1. One of the features of my work is 'convenient office hours / timings'.

If you are having a conversation with someone regarding your work and you are telling someone this then I'd suggest that the above sentence does work best.

Answer (score -2):

'a' denotes on the existence of the body, and the 'one' denotes the entity of the body.  Existence is not a countable term, but entities can be counted. 'a' just indicates the simple presence, but the 'the' indicates the specific presence. There is no countability in the 'the'. 
Pramod Kumar Agrawal